# asp.net/jQuery: post data with jQuery to a popup [IE]

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, post, popup

I'm trying to post data with jQuery in an asp.net application to a popup.

If the popup opens, I'm getting three errors.
The first error is:

```
 Errror: the value of the property is null or undefined not a function object
```

*(error code [code is in popup site]:http://www.suckmypic.net/26449/e65f2d77.png, 
orig. code [code is in popup site]:http://www.suckmypic.net/26450/7dfdf013.png)*

then I'm getting `two errors` of private functions which are included correctly.

Then - if I'm **reloading** the popup window, **everything is working fine.**

I open the popup in this way:

```
$.post('popup.aspx', { X: $("#X1").val(), XX: varX, XXX: varXY, Z: varZ}, function (result) {

  hWndHelp = window.open('', 'help', cStyle);
  hWndHelp.focus();
  hWndHelp.document.open();
  hWndHelp.document.write(result);
  hWndHelp.document.close();
});
```

*(it's stored in a function that I'm calling on pressing the f1 key which is working fine)*

I'm referencing in the mainpage and in the popup window all my functions and the jquery library.

*Edit*

The code for the `cStyle` var:

```
var WIN_STYLE_RESIZE =
    'resizable = yes, ' +
    'status = yes, ' +
    'scrollbars = yes';

var cStyle =
        WIN_STYLE_RESIZE + ', ' +
        'width = ' + w + ', ' +
        'height = ' + h + ', ' +
        'top = ' + y + ', ' +
        'left = ' + x;
```

*(w, h, y, x are calculated numbers, basing on window size)*

If I change it simply to `'width=600,height=400'`, the error still occurs.

If I send my variables via `get` it also works, but i need to hide the variables in the URL.

**Working** get method:

```
var getUrl = "popup.aspx?X="+$('#X1').val()+"&....";
hWndHelp = window.open(getUrl, 'help', cStyle);
```

*Another Edit:*
Just tried chrome and firefox - no error there. But I need the code to work with **IE**.

Comment: in witch line you get the first error ?

Comment: line 2 (line 1 is empty)

Comment: I lost you, can you point this out on the code ?

Comment: http://www.suckmypic.net/26235/09d39c98.png

Comment: If the error is on the first code line in the method, that only references `window` (which is always available) and `cStyle` which is not in the function parameters, I have to assume the reference to the cStyle variable is invalid then. Can you show the code that manipulates that variable? Though I'm not sure what even a null cStyle would do that would cause that particular error message to be given. You may want to post more of the code because I suspect there are interactions that are important that you haven't shown us.

Comment: If I change it to e.g. `'width=600,height=400'`, the error still occurs.

Comment: @KeithL. The capture image for the error is not actually help because the error is hit in the full function and I can not see it. It is possible to show on capture the full yellow function that is hit, or even better, it is possible to run it with google chrome with console open to see all the errors ?

Comment: okay, i've updated the error code. It's not possible to show it with chrome or firefox, because apparently the error only occurs in IE. But I need that to work in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all thanks for the replies.

I've tried every answer, but I'm still always get the errors in internet explorer.

I've found a workaround, but it does not make me happy because i think generating a new form with input fields is too much for my needs.

Since it's the only working option for posting my data into a popup without getting the jQuery error, I've decided to use it.

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "popup.aspx");
form.setAttribute("target", "help");

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "hidden";
input.name = "X";
input.value = $("#X").val();
form.appendChild(input);

var input2 = document.createElement("input");
input2.type = "hidden";
input2.name = "XX";
input2.value = varX;
form.appendChild(input2);

var input3 = document.createElement("input");
input3.type = "hidden";
input3.name = "XXX";
input3.value = varXY;
form.appendChild(input3);

var input4 = document.createElement("input");
input4.type = "hidden";
input4.name = "Z";
input4.value = varZ;
form.appendChild(input4);

document.body.appendChild(form);

hWndHelp = window.open("about:blank", "help", cStyle);
hWndHelp.focus();

form.submit();
document.body.removeChild(form);
```

*original source:*
http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/2010/07/08/javascript-http-post-data-to-new-window-or-pop-up/

Answer (score 2):

Give some time to open the `window` before accessing it. Try this.

```
$.post('popup.aspx', { X: $("#X1").val(), XX: varX, XXX: varXY, Z: varZ}, function (result) {

  var hWndHelp = window.open('', 'help', cStyle);
  setTimeout(function(){
     hWndHelp.focus();
     hWndHelp.document.open();
     hWndHelp.document.write(result);
     hWndHelp.document.close();
  }, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess jquery library are getting loaded on both pages.

And also you  have included $.post in $(function() { ....... }

$.post shorthand function for $.ajax , so it works as asynchronous . 
I suggest to make it synchronous if possible.

Comment: so, how would you do that?
I tried:
function myFunction(){
`$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    window.open('popup.aspx', 'help', cStyle);
 $('#myForm').target = 'help';
}); $('#myForm').submit();
}`
When I'm pressing `F1` (I'm calling my function in this way as i had described), a window opens, but in the next second the main page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'popup.aspx',
  data: { X: $("#X1").val(), XX: varX, XXX: varXY, Z: varZ},
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

     var hWndHelp = window.open('about:blank', 'help', cStyle);

     hWndHelp.focus();
     hWndHelp.document.open();
     hWndHelp.document.write(data);
     hWndHelp.document.close();

  },
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a jQuery plugin to do this. Doesn't have to be jQuery, but mine is.

```
(function ($) {
    $.submitFormToPopup = function (action, params, target, windowOpts) {
        var formID = 'submitFormToPopup';
        var form = $('<form />')
            .attr('method', 'post')
            .attr('action', action)
            .attr('target', target)
            .attr('id', formID);
        $.each(params, function (key, value) {
            form.append($('<input />')
                .attr('type', 'hidden')
                .attr('name', key)
                .attr('value', value));
        });
        $(document.body).append(form);
        window.open('about:blank', target, windowOpts);
        form.submit();
        $(document.body).remove('#' + formID);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing jQuery in popup.aspx. Make sure it´s included.