# jquery send input field values to popup pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, post, popup

I have a form with a table that displays data from a mysql table,it has one field that requires user input. each row also contains a div. The form then has two functions.

the first function is to display information from an external PHP page which processes the values on the input fields in each row and sends the result to the row div in the form of an result

The first function works perfectly and here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function get(row){      //row being processed, defined in onchange="get(x)"
        $.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',{     //data posted to external page
        postvarposition: form["position"+row].value,        //variable equal to input box, sent to external page
        postvarjob: form["job"+row].value,      //variable equal to input box, sent to external page
        postvarperson: form["person"+row].value,        //variable equal to drop down list, sent to external page
        postrow: row},      //variable equal row being processed, sent to external page
            function(output){ 
                $('#training'+row).html(output).show();     //display external results in row div
                    });
                }
</script>
```

The second function I require help with. I need to almost repeat the same javascript function again. however instead of sending the row variables to an external page, I want to send them to a popup page. This function should be triggered when I click the  in the div.

I have the below javascript for the popup.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Popup window code
    function newPopup(url) {
            popupWindow = window.open(      url,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=1000,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
    }
    </script>

What I want to do is send the variables to the popup page, the same variables that were sent to the external page.

so what I am aiming for is something like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {

            function get(row){      //row being processed, defined in onchange="get(x)"
        $.post ('trainingneeded.php',{      //my popup page
        postvarposition: form["position"+row].value,        //these variables must be posted to the popup page
        postvarjob: form["job"+row].value,      //these variables must be posted to the popup page
        postvarperson: form["person"+row].value,        //these variables must be posted to the popup page
        postrow: row},      //these variables must be posted to the popup page
        );
        }
    popupWindow = window.open( //open popup with the above variables posted to it
        url,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=1000,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
```

How can I get the above to work? is using an href the best idea or can the div have an onclick event.

Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to post to a popup window. You can include those variables in the url and to it as a get.

Or you can add target="_blank' to the form, and let it open a new window that way.

It won't be a popup window, but these days browsers mostly block those, or open them in tabs anyway, so it may not matter.

One other option is to open the popup with blank, and then use javascript to simply `write()` the page contents to it.

See also: [asp.net/jQuery: post data with jQuery to a popup [IE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130753/asp-net-jquery-post-data-with-jquery-to-a-popup-ie?rq=1)